# override Sub finalize to make sure connection to DataBase is closed

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am connecting to Access Database and I am wondering if overriding Sub finalize in my cconnectionDB.vb would be useful:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Common
Imports System.IO

Public Class DbConn
    Private DataCon As DbConnection
    Private DBConnectionOpen As Boolean = False

     Protected Overrides Sub finalize()
            Try
                DataCon.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub

    Public Sub OpenDatabaseConnection()
        Try
            DataCon.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New System.Exception("Error opening data connection.", ex.InnerException)
            DBConnectionOpen = False
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        DBConnectionOpen = True
    End Sub 

    Public Sub CloseDatabaseConnection()
        DataCon.Close()
        DBConnectionOpen = False
    End Sub


   ''' <summary>
    ''' Creates a new connection to an Access database
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="FileName">The full path of the Access file</param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New(ByVal FileName As String)
        'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;
        Dim fileData As FileInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(FileName)
        DataCon = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim csb As OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder = New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder
        csb.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & FileName
        Select Case fileData.Extension.ToLower
            Case ".mdb" : csb.Add("Provider", "Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0")
            Case ".accdb" : csb.Add("Provider", "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0")
        End Select
        DataCon.ConnectionString = csb.ConnectionString
        Try
            DataCon.Open()
            DataCon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New System.Exception("Unable to connect to database.", ex.InnerException)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not terribly useful.  The `Finalize` deconstructor won't be called until the garbage collector gets around to destroying the object.  And, since the `DbConn` object would be the only thing that has a reference to the `DbConnection` object, it would automatically destroy that at the same time anyway.  If you want to free the connection as soon as you are done with it, the recommended method is to implement the `IDisposable` interface in your class.  For instance:

```vb
Private Class DbConn
    Implements IDisposable

    Private DataCon As DbConnection
    Private disposedValue As Boolean

    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
        If Not Me.disposedValue Then
            If disposing Then
                Try
                    DataCon.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                End Try
            End If
        End If
        disposedValue = True
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        Dispose(True)
        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, if you implement `IDisposable`, your work isn't done there.  The `Dispose` method on `IDisposable` objects never gets called automatically.  You need to tell the object when you are done with it by calling the Dispose method manually.  Alternatively, you could use a `Using` block:

```vb
Using d As New DbConn
    ' The DbConn.Dispose method automatically gets called once execution leaves this Using block
End Using
```

Comment: but still I need to override ´finlize´ or where should I put it?

Comment: No, there's no reason, in this case, to override `Finalize`.